# Is there a way to connect many separate Xero clients to my mutli user app?

Tags: client, multi-tenant, xero-api

I have a multi-user Student Management System, that hosts hundreds of clients. Many of these clients use Xero and would like us to push invoices in to their system for the various events that happen within our system. I have created an App and have successfully worked the gears of OAuth, but I only appear to be able to connect to the same Xero account that my developer account is attached to? I can see the Demo account and my soon-to-expire trial account as tenants but that is it. My client_id and client_secret seem to be what dictate what tenants I can see.

Is there a way that any one of my clients can set up their own instance of our software to access their own Xero account? Surely they wouldn't have to become a developer to do so?

I am probably going about this completely wrong ... and would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no-one else will fall in to this noob trap ... my problems were caused by being actively logged in to my own Xero account in another tab, so the initial login step was skipped and it was always requesting authorisation for my account. Presumably (and I'll check this with a second demo account), the account I log in to will be the right one for the client doing the set up.

Duh ...

(It's almost like I need to post a question on SO, so as to help me solve it myself, as this is not the first time ...)